# How to improve the speed of an aggregate operation on a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a pandas dataframe named `data_1` like this:

```
tenant_id  tenant_class_id tenant_date
100         10001           2004-01-10
100         10001           2004-08-25
101         10001           2016-09-20
102         10002           2013-07-12
103         10003           2011-04-05
103         10004           2002-05-05
103         10003           2003-12-26
```

My aim is to find the earliest/first `tenant_date` for each `tenant_id`. The `tenant_id` is in `long` format and `tenant_date` is in `datetime64` format

I use this code for computing it:

```
output = data_1.groupby(['tenant_id']).apply(lambda x: x.nsmallest(1, 'tenant_date')).reset_index(drop=1)
```

This works perfectly fine for smaller datasets, but my `data_1` contains about 200 million rows. This code never gets completed. I have enough memory with about 244 GB of RAM.
Is there a more efficient way to do this fastly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sort then use `drop_duplicates`.  But make sure to turn the date column into datetime first.

```
df['tenant_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['tenant_date'])
df.sort_values(['tenant_id', 'tenant_date']).drop_duplicates('tenant_id')

   tenant_id  tenant_class_id tenant_date
0        100            10001  2004-01-10
2        101            10001  2016-09-20
3        102            10002  2013-07-12
5        103            10004  2002-05-05
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) + [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
output = data_1.sort_values(['tenant_id','tenant_date']).drop_duplicates(['tenant_id'])
```

Or [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) + [`GroupBy.head`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.head.html):

```
output = data_1.sort_values(['tenant_id','tenant_date']).groupby(['tenant_id']).head(1)
```

Or seelct min indices per groups by [`idxmin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmin.html):

```
output = data_1.loc[data_1.groupby(['tenant_id'])['tenant_date'].idxmin()]
```

Or:

```
output = data_1.set_index(['tenant_class_id'])
               .groupby(['tenant_id'])['tenant_date'].nsmallest(1).reset_index()
```

**Timings**:

```
np.random.seed(123)
N = 1000000
L = pd.date_range('2015-01-01', '2018-01-01')

df = pd.DataFrame({'tenant_date': np.random.choice(L, size=N),
                   'tenant_id':np.random.randint(1000,size=N),
                   'tenant_class_id':np.random.randint(1000,size=N)})
print (df)

In [99]: %timeit data_1.sort_values(['tenant_id','tenant_date']).drop_duplicates(['tenant_id'])
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.97 ms per loop

In [100]: %timeit data_1.sort_values(['tenant_id','tenant_date']).groupby(['tenant_id']).head(1)
1000 loops, best of 3: 2.07 ms per loop

In [101]: %timeit data_1.loc[data_1.groupby(['tenant_id'])['tenant_date'].idxmin()]
100 loops, best of 3: 2.04 ms per loop

In [102]: %timeit data_1.set_index(['tenant_class_id']).groupby(['tenant_id'])['tenant_date'].nsmallest(1).reset_index()
100 loops, best of 3: 8.64 ms per loop

In [103]: %timeit data_1.groupby(['tenant_id']).apply(lambda x: x.nsmallest(1, 'tenant_date')).reset_index(drop=1)
100 loops, best of 3: 11.4 ms per loop
```

**Caveat**

The results do not address performance given the number of groups, which will affect timings a lot for some of these solutions.